# Bootstrap 5 - Cover page example with fixed-top nav and scrolling content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am totally struggling trying to customize the [bootstrap 5 cover page example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/cover/).
I very much like this design and expecially the header and footer (without toggle, when reduced brand stays on a single line, etc..).

I would like to have a page with more content, scrolling in the middle, while fixing the navbar and the footer. Changing footer class to `footer fixex-bottom` easily led me where I wanted.

I have 2 problems:

1. Can you help me fix the navbar top (without its text expanding full
   width)? I want to be able to scroll with the navbar in this exact
   style, remainng fixed top, but not going full page with its content. I am also trying to change the color.
2. When I have little text, this should be centered in the page between header and footer, not aligned top.

[See this CodePen example.](https://codepen.io/andreafc/pen/poRPPjp)
My first time with CodePen, so please be patient :)

Comment: I guess you're looking for something like this.. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/navbar-fixed/

Comment: Not, really. I considered that, but it is not the style I am looking for. Also that bar extends to full width, wherea I want to keep the style shown in the cover page. Thanks anyway for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the HTML structure I would have used, but I made it work using your code as base. Here's a fork I made of your pen: [Fork example](https://codepen.io/riios/pen/oNBWweW)

This is what I added to make it work:

1. Added the class fixed-top to your yellow header. This expanded as you wanted, and stayed fixed on the top. To keep it on the same with as your content, I added a bootstrap container class to keep everything with a max with and centered. I then added this class to your already made style in your css to keep the same max-width as your cover-container class.
2. To keep page contents vertically centered, I created a container for them to be together inside  (borders for reference). I wanted the page to be at least 100vh tall, so I could center everything properly to something. I suggest you to read Bootstrap documentation to learn what their classes do. The classes I added set `display: flex;`, and `align-items: center;` py-5 is mostly for style.

Comment: thank you, sounds good in the codepen, I'll test it :) I see you got a downvote from someone and I am wondering why?

Comment: PS. What is the responsive HTML structure you would have used for this purpose?

Comment: Not sure why I got downvoted, it's my first contribution to SO haha. I'd use .section (optional) > .container > .row > .col-12 (or whatever column width you would use). This is Bootstraps layout classes and structure. Take a look at the Layout section in their docs.